# Can a global variable be incremented in a class in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to increment a global variable inside a c++ class but can not configure out how to do so

```
int line = 0;
int ivar = 0;
int cvar = 0;
int svar = 0;

class file {
protected:
    char name[50];
    string read;
    string write;
    ifstream readfile;
    ofstream writefile;
    int i;
    int j;
};
```

I want to increment the cvar variable inside the class file. Something like

```
class file {
protected:
    char name[50];  cvar++;
    string read;
    string write;
    ifstream readfile;
    ofstream writefile;
    int i;
    int j;
};
```

But the compiler gives error if done this way. Can someone devise an alternative method to do so?

Comment: You can increment it inside of class method. Also global variables are not good.

Comment: You cannot put arbitrary code in a class declaration. As for proposing alternatives, we would have to know what you're trying to achieve. (P.S: `ivar`, `cvar` and `svar` are bad variable names)

Comment: _But the compiler gives error if done this way._ Did you try.. I don't know.. Reading the error? That may have given you a clue on what you were doing wrong.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius the error says says that "this declaration has no class or type specifier".

Comment: @Borgleader I am trying to add a counter to my program that counts the number of character type variables declared in the complete program.

Comment: @Zainzam Hence, you should've concluded that compiler was expecting a declaration. `cvar++` is not a declaration. You should read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) if you are having these kinds of problems.

Comment: @Zainzam you can't do this. BTW why do you want to do this ? It doesn't make much sense. Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2):

You can, but the incrementation needs to be in a *method* of the class.

Using the *default constructor* would work, and this has the bonus that the incrementation happens when you create a new instance of your class:

```
file::file() /*ToDo - declare this in the class definition*/
{
    cvar++;
}
```

Finally, it would be a good idea to use `std::atomic<int>` as the type for `cvar`, in order to prevent concurrency issues (namely simultaneous read and writes on `cvar`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't put lines of code to be executed in a class definition. They need to be in a function.

Perhaps in your case, a constructor:

```
class file {
public:
    file() {
        cvar++;
    }

protected:
    char name[50];  
    string read;
    string write;
    ifstream readfile;
    ofstream writefile;
    int i;
    int j;
};
```

There are several better approaches than global variables - which depend on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> I am trying to add a counter to my program that counts the number of
>   character type variables declared in the complete program.

Global variables are not nice. Also "manually" incrementing a counter whenever you use a `char[]` isnt nice either. I would probably use something similar to this:

```
struct MyString {
    std::string theString;
    static int counter;
    MyString() { counter++;}
};

int MyString::counter = 0;
```

and then

```
struct file {
    MyString name;
    /*...*/
};
```

The `static` variable acts more or less like a global, but it doest pollute your namespace, because it is where it belongs (`MyString::counter`). Further, if you use `MyString` you have no chance to forget incrementing the counter each time you need a string. Last but not least I changed from `char[]` to `std::string`, because unless there is a reason `std::string` should be prefered over `char[]`.